# How to make sidebar scrollable and the deep nested child pop up element ignore the scrollable property

Tags: css, vuejs3, tailwind-css

I am utilizing Vue 3 with Tailwind CSS and Headless UI for my project. I need to make the sidebar navigation scrollable as well as make the pop up menu appear outside the sidebar navigation. As the menu items within the sidebar navigation will increase in the future so I need to make the sidebar scrollable, but in such case when I am trying to add `overflow-y-scroll` on the main parent element, the pop up menu appears inside the dimensions of the sidebar instead of outside. How can this be overcome? Please if some one can spare some time to guide and shed some light on this, I am really stuck here since weeks, I would really be grateful and appreciate your time and support!

Code:

```
<template>
    <div
        :class="[
            !sidebarCollapse ? 'sm:w-52' : 'sm:w-12',
            'hidden sm:fixed sm:bottom-0 sm:left-0 sm:top-12 sm:z-50 sm:block sm:overflow-y-scroll sm:border-r sm:border-gray-200 sm:bg-neutral-50 sm:pb-4',
        ]"
    >
        <div class="border-b border-gray-200">
            <div
                class="flex h-10 w-[calc(3rem-0.0625rem)] shrink-0 items-center justify-center"
            >
                <button
                    type="button"
                    class="p-1.5 text-gray-500 hover:text-gray-600"
                    @click="sidebarCollapse = !sidebarCollapse"
                >
                    <span class="sr-only">Expand sidebar</span>
                    <Bars3Icon class="h-5 w-5" aria-hidden="true" />
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>

        <nav class="mt-8">
            <div class="flex flex-col">
                <ul role="list" class="space-y-1">
                    <li
                        v-for="item in navigation"
                        :key="item.name"
                        class="px-1"
                    >
                        <a
                            v-if="!item.children"
                            :href="item.href"
                            :class="[
                                item.current
                                    ? 'bg-gray-100 '
                                    : 'hover:bg-gray-100',
                                'group flex h-10 w-full items-center justify-center gap-x-3 rounded-md p-2.5 text-standard font-semibold leading-6 text-gray-700',
                            ]"
                        >
                            <span
                                class="-mx-2.5 flex w-10 flex-none items-center justify-center"
                            >
                                <component
                                    :is="item.icon"
                                    class="h-5 w-5 shrink-0 text-gray-400"
                                    aria-hidden="true"
                                />
                            </span>
                            <span
                                :class="[
                                    !sidebarCollapse
                                        ? 'flex-1 items-center'
                                        : 'sr-only',
                                ]"
                            >
                                {{ item.name }}
                            </span>
                        </a>
                        <div v-else>
                            <Disclosure
                                v-if="!sidebarCollapse"
                                as="div"
                                v-slot="{ open }"
                            >
                                <DisclosureButton
                                    :class="[
                                        item.current
                                            ? 'bg-gray-100 '
                                            : 'hover:bg-gray-100',
                                        'group flex h-10 w-full items-center justify-center gap-x-3 rounded-md p-2.5 text-standard font-semibold leading-6 text-gray-700',
                                    ]"
                                >
                                    <span
                                        class="-mx-2.5 flex w-10 flex-none items-center justify-center"
                                    >
                                        <component
                                            :is="item.icon"
                                            class="h-5 w-5 shrink-0 text-gray-400"
                                            aria-hidden="true"
                                        />
                                    </span>
                                    <span
                                        :class="[
                                            !sidebarCollapse
                                                ? 'flex flex-1 items-center'
                                                : 'sr-only',
                                        ]"
                                    >
                                        {{ item.name }}
                                        <ChevronRightIcon
                                            :class="[
                                                open
                                                    ? 'rotate-90 text-gray-500'
                                                    : 'text-gray-400',
                                                'ml-auto h-4 w-4 shrink-0',
                                            ]"
                                            aria-hidden="true"
                                        />
                                    </span>
                                </DisclosureButton>
                                <DisclosurePanel as="ul" class="mt-1 px-2">
                                    <li
                                        v-for="subItem in item.children"
                                        :key="subItem.name"
                                    >
                                        <DisclosureButton
                                            as="a"
                                            :href="subItem.href"
                                            :class="[
                                                subItem.current
                                                    ? 'bg-gray-100'
                                                    : 'hover:bg-gray-100',
                                                'block h-10 w-full rounded-md py-2 pl-9 pr-2 text-standard leading-6 text-gray-700',
                                            ]"
                                        >
                                            <span
                                                :class="[
                                                    !sidebarCollapse
                                                        ? 'flex-1 items-center'
                                                        : 'sr-only',
                                                ]"
                                            >
                                                {{ subItem.name }}
                                            </span>
                                        </DisclosureButton>
                                    </li>
                                </DisclosurePanel>
                            </Disclosure>
                            <Menu v-else as="div" class="relative">
                                <MenuButton
                                    :class="[
                                        item.current
                                            ? 'bg-gray-100'
                                            : 'hover:bg-gray-100',
                                        'group flex h-10 w-full items-center justify-center rounded-md p-2.5 text-standard font-semibold leading-6 text-gray-700',
                                    ]"
                                >
                                    <span
                                        class="-mx-2.5 flex w-10 flex-none items-center justify-center"
                                    >
                                        <component
                                            :is="item.icon"
                                            class="h-5 w-5 shrink-0 text-gray-400"
                                            aria-hidden="true"
                                        />
                                    </span>
                                </MenuButton>
                                <transition
                                    enter-active-class="transition ease-out duration-100"
                                    enter-from-class="transform opacity-0 scale-95"
                                    enter-to-class="transform opacity-100 scale-100"
                                    leave-active-class="transition ease-in duration-75"
                                    leave-from-class="transform opacity-100 scale-100"
                                    leave-to-class="transform opacity-0 scale-95"
                                >
                                    <MenuItems
                                        :class="[
                                            'absolute left-14 top-0 z-10 mt-px w-36 origin-top-right rounded-md bg-white py-2 shadow-md ring-1 ring-gray-900/5 focus:outline-none',
                                        ]"
                                    >
                                        <MenuItem
                                            v-for="subItem in item.children"
                                            :key="subItem.name"
                                            v-slot="{ active }"
                                        >
                                            <a
                                                :href="subItem.href"
                                                :class="[
                                                    active ? 'bg-gray-50' : '',
                                                    'block px-3 py-1 text-standard leading-6 text-gray-500',
                                                ]"
                                            >
                                                {{ subItem.name }}
                                            </a>
                                        </MenuItem>
                                    </MenuItems>
                                </transition>
                            </Menu>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import { ref } from 'vue'
import {
    Menu,
    MenuButton,
    MenuItem,
    MenuItems,
    Disclosure,
    DisclosureButton,
    DisclosurePanel,
} from '@headlessui/vue'
import {
    Bars3Icon,
    CalendarIcon,
    ChartPieIcon,
    DocumentDuplicateIcon,
    FolderIcon,
    HomeIcon,
    UsersIcon,
} from '@heroicons/vue/24/outline'
import { ChevronRightIcon } from '@heroicons/vue/20/solid'

const navigation = [
    { name: 'Dashboard', href: '#', icon: HomeIcon, current: true },
    {
        name: 'Teams',
        icon: UsersIcon,
        current: false,
        children: [
            { name: 'Engineering', href: '#' },
            { name: 'Human Resources', href: '#' },
            { name: 'Customer Success', href: '#' },
        ],
    },
    {
        name: 'Projects',
        icon: FolderIcon,
        current: false,
        children: [
            { name: 'GraphQL API', href: '#' },
            { name: 'iOS App', href: '#' },
            { name: 'Android App', href: '#' },
            { name: 'New Customer Portal', href: '#' },
        ],
    },
    { name: 'Calendar', href: '#', icon: CalendarIcon, current: false },
    {
        name: 'Documents',
        href: '#',
        icon: DocumentDuplicateIcon,
        current: false,
    },
    { name: 'Reports', href: '#', icon: ChartPieIcon, current: false },
]

const sidebarCollapse = ref(true)
</script>
```

Current Scenario:
[image]

Expected Result:
[image]

Comment: You seem to have omitted the code for the variables `sidebarCollapse`, `navigation`, `sidebarDropdownMenuComponent` and `setSidebarDropdownMenuCurrentPosition` and also you seem to have omitted the code for the components `Bars3Icon`, `ChevronRightIcon`. You have also omitted the `<script>` section for this component. Consider including the missing pieces to have a greater chance of receiving assistance.

Comment: @Wongjn Really thank you for your advice, have updated the code as per the criteria. Please if you can spare some time to have a look, I would really be glad!

Comment: [css-tricks.com: Popping Out of Hidden Overflow](https://css-tricks.com/popping-hidden-overflow/)

Comment: @CBroe Hey, thanks for your response! Have tried this already but no result. The deep nested menu which I need to pop up outside the sidebar navigation, I need it to be relative to its descendent parent yet ignore the `overflow-y-scroll` property accordingly, please if you can spare some time to have a look at the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to render the menu outside the `overflow-y-scroll` element. You could do this using the built-in [`<Teleport>` component](https://vuejs.org/guide/built-ins/teleport.html).

As a crude example to get you started:

1. Wrap the `<MenuItems>` with `<Teleport>`:

   ```html
   <Teleport to="body">
     <transition …>
       <MenuItems …>
   ```

   This moves the sub-menu outside the `overflow-y-scroll` element but now the elements are positioned incorrectly.
2. Set [template `refs`](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-refs.html#refs-inside-v-for) for each of the top-level menu items:

   ```html
   <li … :ref="(el) => item.el = el">
   ```
3. Apply a `top` value equal to the distance of the top-level menu item's top edge with the top of the viewport:

   ```html
   <MenuItems
     … 
     :style="{ top: item.el?.getBoundingClientRect().top + 'px' }"
   >
   ```

View a working example in [this StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-wg4yzp?file=src%2FApp.vue).

Comment: This is perfect to what I wanted, I am really grateful to you, and thank you for the support and help you have provided.